# Contraction of Kronecker delta = 4

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, notation, tensor-calculus, trace

This suggests, as a shortcut notation, the concept of lowering indices; from any vector we
can construct a (0, 1) tensor defined by contraction with the metric:
$$A_\nu ≡ g_{\mu\nu}A^\mu$$

so that the dot product becomes $$g_{\mu\nu}A^\mu B^\nu = A_\nu B^\nu$$
 We also define the inverse metric $g^{\mu\nu}$ as the matrix inverse of the metric tensor:
$$g^{\mu\nu}g_{\nu\rho} = δ^\mu_\rho$$

where $δ^\mu_\rho$ is the (spacetime) Kronecker delta. (Convince yourself that this expression really
does correspond to matrix multiplication.) Then we have the ability to raise indices:
$$A^\mu = g^{\mu\nu}A_\nu$$
Note that raising an index on the metric yields the Kronecker delta, so we have
$$g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu} = δ^\mu_\mu = 4$$

I don't understand why $δ^\mu_\mu = 4$. Shouldn't it equal 1?

Comment: The quantity $\delta_\nu^\nu$ is called the trace, and the trace of the Kronecker delta is indeed 4. can you clarify what is confusing you about this? Is that you think $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu}$ should be equal to 1? If so, I suspect you're mixing up $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\mu\nu}$, which gives the trace of $g$, with $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\nu\rho}$, which multiplies the two matrices and gives the matrix $I$.

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks! That was exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: In that case the question (v3) is essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66394/2451

Comment: A repeated index on $\delta^\mu{}_\mu$ implies a summation (summation convention). Then what we truly mean is $\delta^\mu_\mu = \sum_{\mu=0}^3 \delta^\mu_\mu = 1+1+1+1 = 4$. More generally, it is equal to $d$, the dimension of space-time.