# $x'^i_j x^j_k = n\delta^i_k$ rather than $1\delta^i_j$?

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, notation, differentiation, trace

These are my calculations
$$x'^i_j x^j_k = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x'^k} = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x'^k} =n \delta^i_k\ne \delta^i_k?$$

But in general relativity, they always just take $x'^i_kx^j_k=\delta^i_k$ in any dimension of manifold? Surely that only holds in a $1$-manifold?

**Notation:**
$x'^i_j=\frac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x^j}$, $x^i_j=\frac{\partial x^i}{x'^j}$, where we have two coordinate systems $x'=(x'^1,\cdots,x'^n)$ and $x=(x^1,\cdots,x^n)$.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66394/2451

Comment: What are $x^i$ and $x'^i$?

Comment: @Javier See edit. Apologies for not writing this.

Answer (score 2):

You've misapplied the chain rule; we have $\dfrac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x'^k}=\sum_j \dfrac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x^j}\dfrac{\partial x^j}{\partial x'^k}$, so $\sum_j x'^i_j x^j_k = \dfrac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x'^k}=\delta^i_k$.

Comment: Have you used Einstein notation in the last steps? I.e. that is a sum over $j=1,\cdots n$ and hence is actually $n\delta^i_k$?

Comment: I'll update the answer to make this issue clearer.

Comment: I still don't understand, it would appear that:
$$\sum_j x'^i_jx^j_k= (\sum_{j=1}^n 1)\frac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x'^k}=(n)\frac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x'^k} = n\delta_k^i ?$$

Comment: @DisplayName the chain rule already includes the sum over $j$, you can't factor it out.